# How to do a vlookup in dax in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I know I need to use LOOKUPVALUE() but I still can't seem to find the solution.  This is my table:

```
DocumentNumber  Line  RODoc#
14C00001        AA    
14C00001        AB
14C00001        AC
14C00001A       AA
14C00001A       AB
14C00001B       AA
14R12345        AA    14C00001B
14R12346        AC    14C00001
```

I need to create a new column that returns something (could be 1, TRUE, or any identifier) that populates a value on the row where the DocumentNumber and Line match the Line and RODoc#.

So, in my example, the result would look like this:

```
DocumentNumber  Line  RODoc#      NewColumn
14C00001        AA                
14C00001        AB 
14C00001        AC                1
14C00001A       AA
14C00001A       AB                
14C00001B       AA                1
14R12345        AA    14C00001B
14R12346        AC    14C00001
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve what you want

**`LOOKUPVALUE`**

```
LOOKUPVALUE =
IF (
    'Table'[DocumentNumber]
        = LOOKUPVALUE (
            'Table'[RODoc#],
            'Table'[RODoc#], 'Table'[DocumentNumber],
            'Table'[Line], 'Table'[Line]
        ),
    1
)
```

But I find LOOKUPVALUE with performance issue

**`MAXX Iterator`**

```
MAXX =
IF (
    'Table'[DocumentNumber]
        = MAXX (
            FILTER (
                'Table',
                'Table'[RODoc#] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[DocumentNumber] )
                    && 'Table'[Line] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[Line] )
            ),
            'Table'[RODoc#]
        ),
    1
)
```

**`IN Operator`**

```
IN =
IF (
    'Table'[DocumentNumber]
        = IF (
            ( 'Table'[DocumentNumber], 'Table'[Line] )
                IN SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[RODoc#], 'Table'[Line] ),
            'Table'[DocumentNumber]
        ),
    1
)
```

[image: S1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NewColumn = 
  VAR doc_number = [DocumentNumber]
  RETURN CALCULATE(
       DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[RODoc#]), 
       ALL('Table'), 
       'Table'[RODoc#] = doc_number )
```

But you probably can model your data a bit better to give you the result you're after.